# I would like to get image url from json file : image.60x60.url

Tags: angularjs, json, pinterest

I'm working with the pinterest api . And I would like to retrieve the image url . But when I Write : image.60x60.url I got Syntax Error: Token '.60' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression .

Comment: Please post your code, preferably within a link to plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net. Also include relevant links to the Pinterest API docs that you're using to build your feature.

Comment: this is my code :
var url = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/following/users/?access_token='+$localStorage.accessTokenPinterest+'&fields=first_name%2Cid%2Clast_name%2Curl%2Caccount_type%2Cusername%2Cbio%2Ccounts%2Cimage';
  https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/following/users/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx
  $http.get(url)
   .success(function(data){
    console.log(data.image.60x60.url);
and this is the response :
image:
    Object
        60x60:
           Object
              url:"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/hmonson30-
              1415996435_60.jpg"

Comment: Please update your question with your code. The easier you make it for others to see what you're working with, the most likely it will be that you receive help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help  must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.